# Altair slider transform data

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I've been enjoying using Altair for a couple of weeks now but I'm stuck on how to solve a problem. I've been trying to do a simple plot of average temp data vs. month and using a slider widget to filter though the years. I can get the plot to work but as soon as I use the slider option it doesn't show any data. I tried just using the selection option but that didn't work. I just don't know how to handle the transform option. I use the *US Population Over Time* example as a guide.

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum, if_
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiritR/datpr6754/master/prtas_1901_2015.csv'


slider = alt.binding_range(min=1900, max=2020, step=10)
year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['Year'], bind=slider)

alt.Chart(path).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Month_Name:O'),
    alt.Y('tas:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(20, 28))),
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=300,
).add_selection(
    year
).transform_calculate(
   ????
).transform_filter(
    year.ref()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV data are being parsed as strings rather than numbers. When you use the slider to select a date (say `1959`) it is filters the data to check which values are equal to that... and since the data are strings, `"1959" != 1959` and the resulting subset is empty.

You can force the column to be parsed as a number, and then the slider will work correctly. For example:

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiritR/datpr6754/master/prtas_1901_2015.csv'
data = alt.UrlData(url=path, format=alt.CsvDataFormat(parse={'Year': 'number'}))

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1901, max=2015, step=1)
year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['Year'], bind=slider)

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Month_Name:O'),
    alt.Y('tas:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(20, 28))),
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=300,
).add_selection(
    year
).transform_filter(
    year
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I know it was simple that I was missing :(   Works perfect now. Thanks for the great support.

Comment: Sorry for the follow-up question, but is there a way to make the selection start at a specific point (year in this case)? the default is all (or none) until the slider is move.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is not at the moment. It's been reported as a bug here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/599